# Подстановки (wildcards) в полнотекстовом поиске SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, полнотекстовый-поиск, wildcards

Разбираюсь с возможностями полнотекстового поиска, а точнее - с поиском по заданным шаблонам. Наткнулся на [эту статью](https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-full-text-search-for-symbols-in-SQL-Server), краткая выдержка, которая меня заинтересовала:

> FTS differentiates between a symbol defined as a wildcard and the
>   other symbols. Here are a few symbols used in FTS as wildcards:

```
+==================================+========+==============================================================================================================================================================================================================+
|            Expression            | Syntax |                                                                                                 Description                                                                                                  |
+==================================+========+==============================================================================================================================================================================================================+
| Any Character                    | .      | Matches any single character except a line break.                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Zero or more                     | *      | Matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding expression, making all possible matches.                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| One or more                      | +      | Matches at least one occurrence of the preceding expression.                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Beginning of line                | ^      | Anchors the match string to the beginning of a line                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| End of line                      | $      | Anchors the match string to the end of a line.                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Beginning of word                | <</td> | Matches only when a word begins at this point in the text.                                                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| End of word                      | >      | Matches only when a word ends at this point in the text.                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Line break                       | \n     | Matches a platform-independent line break. In a Replace expression, inserts a line break.                                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Any one character in the set     | [ ]    | Matches any one of the characters within the [ ]. To specify a range of characters, list the starting and ending character separated by a dash (-), as in [a-z].                                             |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Any one character not in the set | [^...] | Matches any character not in the set of characters following the ^.                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Or                               | |      | Matches either the expression before or the one after the OR symbol (|). Mostly used within a group. For example, (sponge|mud) bath matches "sponge bath" and "mud bath."                                    |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Escape                           | \      | Matches the character that follows the backslash (\) as a literal. This allows you to find the characters used in regular expression notation, such as { and ^. For example, ^ Searches for the ^ character. |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tagged expression                | {}     | Matches text tagged with the enclosed expression.                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| C/C++ Identifier                 | :i     | Matches the expression ([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*).                                                                                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Quoted string                    | :q     | Matches the expression (("[^"]*")|('[^']*')).                                                                                                                                                                |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Space or Tab                     | :b     | Matches either space or tab characters.                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Integer                          | :z     | Matches the expression ([0-9]+).                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Про `*` понятно, это документированная возможность, но что насчёт остальных? Действительно ли эти подстановки поддерживаются в SQL Server FTS? Если да, то в каких версиях и какие есть варианты использования, синтаксис?

Гуглил два дня, ничего не нашёл.

Comment: такое ощущение что таблица отсюда взята -  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-2017 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представленная в статье таблица удивительнейшим образом повторяет таблицу из статьи "[Search Text with Regular Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms174214(v=sql.110))". Однако, она относится к использованию регулярных выражений в диалоговом окне "Найти и заменить" в SSMS.

В приведенной вами статье говорится, что FTS игнорирует в принципе вообще все, кроме слов (исключив стоп-слова). И далее там нет никаких попыток применить данные подстановочные символы в `contains`.

В **Example #1: Wildcards** упоминание `\+` вообще никак не влияет на результат запроса. Они игнорируются как знаки препинания.

Далее **Example #2: Non-wildcard symbols**, вообще не понятно почему выдает пустой результат. Ибо при использовании `CONTAINS` запрос `"@"` приведет к ошибке синтаксиса, поскольку содержит не поисковую фразу, а одиночный символ, который не должен заключаться в кавычки, но и все равно не будет найдет в результатах, т.к. в индекс, очевидно, не входит.

После чего далее описывается, как же все таки отфильтровать точную фразу вместе со знаками препинания, используя полнотекстовый индекс. В примере рассматривается поиск фразы `New world!`. И в данном подходе сначала к этой фразе применяется полнотекстовый поиск. Знак  `!` отбрасывается и возвращаются результаты, подходящие просто под `New World`, затем на результаты джойна накладывается условие `WHERE` с конструкцией `LIKE` учитывающей точную фразу.
Тут же с какой то целью есть заметка про различия в производительности, что, конечно, несколько  забавно, когда в запросе участвует всего 10 строк. Основано на том, что `WHERE` выполняется после `JOIN`.

Ну и в завершении, с помощью `case` проводится ранжирование, когда результаты с точным совпадением по `like` попадают на первое место.
Почему-то, правда, там возвращаются ранги `1` и `2`, хотя логичнее было бы возвращать `1` и `key_tbl.rank + 1`. +Дополнение про CTE для исключения столбца из выборки скорее излишнее, `case` можно было впихнуть прямо в `order by`

В целом, статья демонстрирует подход к решению задачи поиска точной фразы со знаками препинания, при этом используя полнотекстовый индекс для предварительного отсечения неподходящих результатов.

Ну а опус с таблицей на совести автора. Возможно, хотели найти таблицу с паттернами `LIKE` (хотя и они тут не в тему) и скопировали не то, что искали. Хотя судя под абзацу перед таблицей это не так. В общем. если выбросить часть с таблицей, статья вполне интересна. Имхо, следует считать, что она попала в статью случайно.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже пришёл к таким выводам. Значит всё-таки кроме `*`   ничего больше для нас нет? :(

Comment: @Anatol дак и `*` тут имеет весьма специфический смысл. это же не подстановва, ее нельзя вписать в середину/начало слова.  Это фильтрация по словоформам. Указанным в статье способом, можно применять фильтрацию по fts-индексу и дальнейшее использование паттернов в  `LIKE` или `PATINDEX`. Прямого использования регулярок в ms sql нет, но есть расширения CLR

Comment: это понятно, но термин для `*` именно `wildcard` везде используется тем не менее